# python-polars are there any updated release notes for new versions?

Tags: python-polars

Are there any updated release notes for python-polars?

This seems to have whats changed untill (2021-10-08) https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/master/py-polars/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: There's a GitHub issue to create automated release notes.  You can track that here: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4391  and here: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/5033

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just very very recently set up the architecture to automate release notes. Here is the latest release as of 2022-10-03: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.14.16